# Mapping between alfresco user group and jbpm swinlane, pooledActors

Tags: workflow, alfresco, jbpm

When I use "**Pooled Review and Approve**" workflow in **jbpm**, I select a "user group". Workflow tasks are created for members of "user group" in starting workflow.

My understanding is

> Selected alfresco user group is mapped to jbpm swimlane, especially
>   pooledActors for this workflow type.

But I don't know where the mapping is located.

My requirement is not to allow task creation for some member of "user group" according to criteria. Any help are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the jbpm swimlane is located in the jbpm xml file where your workflow resides...
examples are:

```
    <swimlane name="reviewer">
       <assignment class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.jbpm.AlfrescoAssignment">
          <actor>#{bpm_assignee}</actor>
       </assignment>
    </swimlane>
```

or

```
   <swimlane name="initiator" />
```

If you want to change the pooledActors in the specific alfresco workflow "Pooled Review and Approve" you should look into:

```
/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/workflow
```

there you'll find the workflow bpmn20.xml definition files.
For your goal you should create two separated groups, "user groups" and "user not allowed group".

So you could put a check in your code, where if a user is in the "user not allowed group", the same user is not allowed to perform the action.
Hope I understood your problem.